# lightroom for video

Tags: editing

I shot an event for a client. The client did not want me to make an after-movie, and they just wanted footage for promotion the following year. So I am supposed to deliver the video files.

I want to be able to trim off the fat from some clips, and perhaps even do some basic cc. It would be a horrible amount of work if I imported all files into Premiere and did this on a per clip basis then export/transcode in batches. I've thought of Catalyst Browse but it doesn't support my file type (ProRes .mov), and Prelude does not seem to be designed for this either, nor do I see a color correction panel (which I can live without).

Any suggestions for a windows computer? I was thinking of a sort of lightroom for video.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried [Blackmagic DaVinci Resolve 12](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/davinciresolve)?

How I understand, it should work fine with multiple files, but you shall check, if it will accept your ProRes files.